# pandas drop() - error - Label [ ] not contained in axis

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using drop() to clear out rows with garbage values (NaN, NaT, '') from certain columns.

```
for index, row in user_data_to_clean.iterrows():    
    if row.email != row.email or row.email == '' or row.email == ' ':
        user_data_to_clean.drop(index, inplace=True)
        email_count = email_count + 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-bb0cb6d83902> in <module>()
     24 
     25         if row.email != row.email or row.email == '' or row.email == ' ':
---> 26             user_data_to_clean.drop(index, inplace=True)
     27             email_count = email_count + 1
     28 

/home/eyebell/local_bin/janacare/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in drop(self, labels, axis, level, inplace, errors)
   1871                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   1872             else:
-> 1873                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   1874             dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   1875             try:

/home/eyebell/local_bin/janacare/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.pyc in drop(self, labels, errors)
   2964             if errors != 'ignore':
   2965                 raise ValueError('labels %s not contained in axis' %
-> 2966                                  labels[mask])
   2967             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   2968         return self.delete(indexer)

ValueError: labels [124] not contained in axis
```

The offending row is:

```
print user_data_to_clean.iloc[124]
user_id                                     656
first_name                            xxxxxxx.A
last_name                                   NaN
username                               xxxxxxxx
email                           xxxxx@gmail.com
phone_number                         7123372613
date_joined                 2013-09-27 00:00:00
first_login                                 NaT
last_activity                               NaT
Name: 182, dtype: object
```

What is the issue here ?

I know an alternate way to achieve my objective is to slice the rows,
but I want to understand what is going wrong here!

Comment: Can you check `user_data_to_clean.loc[124]` instead? `iloc` looks at the position of the row, not the label. You might be trying to drop a row that has previously been dropped.

Comment: @ayhan : Thank you, turns out that was my mistake. I was dropping rows that had already been dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use vectorized [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) rather as `drop` with `iterrows()`, because `iterrows()` is very slow:
For mask by `NaN` and `NaT` use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
print (user_data_to_clean[(user_data_to_clean.email != '') & 
                          (user_data_to_clean.email != ' ') & 
                          (user_data_to_clean.email.notnull()) ])
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

user_data_to_clean = pd.DataFrame({'email':['','aa',' ', np.nan, 'dd'],
                   'a':[7,5,6,4,7],
                   'b':[7,8,9,1,2]})

print (user_data_to_clean)
   a  b email
0  7  7      
1  5  8    aa
2  6  9      
3  4  1   NaN
4  7  2    dd
```

Boolean mask:

```
print ((user_data_to_clean.email != '') &  
       (user_data_to_clean.email != ' ') & 
       (user_data_to_clean.email.notnull())) 

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: email, dtype: bool 

print (user_data_to_clean[(user_data_to_clean.email != '') & 
                          (user_data_to_clean.email != ' ') & 
                          (user_data_to_clean.email.notnull()) ])

   a  b email
1  5  8    aa
4  7  2    dd
```

Comment: I am using the boolean masking method now. iterrows was working very slow. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

i would do it this way:

test DF:

```
In [43]: df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['x@x.x', 'aaa@aaa.com','  ', np.nan, 'a@mail.com', '1', 'xxx@gmail.com', '', np.nan], 'col': np.random.randint(0,100,9)})

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
   col          email
0   89          x@x.x
1   81    aaa@aaa.com
2   82
3   43            NaN
4   71     a@mail.com
5    3              1
6   48  xxx@gmail.com
7   48
8   71            NaN
```

clean up:

```
In [53]: df = df[(df.email.notnull()) & (df.email.str.strip().str.len() > 5)]

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   col          email
1   97    aaa@aaa.com
4   77     a@mail.com
6   47  xxx@gmail.com
```

PS if you want a serious and robust (but slow) email validation use [validate_email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email) module instead

if you need `email_count`, do this after cleaning up:

```
email_count = len(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using the validate_email module. It works great.